# XCode and Archive having issues.. not sure what it could be

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, distribution, profile

I am using Xcode 4.3

I am trying to archive my app and I get 2 warnings

> 1. iPhone/iPod Touch: Icon.png: icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't meet the size requirements.  The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png
>      format (-19014)
> 2. Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.
>      (-19011)

I know I have the Icon in 57x57 pixels. It's called Icon.png
I also have the Retina icon in 114x114 pixels (called Icon@2x.png)

I don't know why the App code sign is failing. I redid my certificates and it builds fine.
It will also archive (even with those warnings)

When I go to the Organizer, I see my Archived apps. I see 2 buttons (Validate and Distribute)

When I click on Validate; I see the names of older apps but not the name of the current app.

I added the current app to the App ID. Setup the distribution profile with the same App ID.
Downloaded and dragged it to Xcode and closed, relaunched Xcode.

Comment: If you locate your icon files in Finder, can you preview/open them? There's a chance they may have been corrupted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why the App code sign is failing. I redid my certificates and it builds fine. It will also archive (even with those warnings)- ***Have you created the distribution profile for the bundle identifier which you are trying to archive. You should select the distribution profile in CODE_SIGNING_ENTITLEMENTS before you archive the app.***

iPhone/iPod Touch: Icon.png: icon dimensions (0 x 0) don't meet the size requirements. The icon file must be 57x57 pixels, in .png format (-19014) - **For this you can visit the below mentioned link.**

http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/02/02/macosx-10.7.3-update-breaks-ios-app-validation

I hope this helps.